# Questions with pending close votes in an audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

I got caught by an [audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/340119) on [Can I recover a deleted file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543159/can-i-recover-a-deleted-file). The question, while upvoted, high-quality, etc., was actually flagged duplicate, and had three votes in support when the audit happened. Now I don't mind failing the occasional audit (there are a few questions I will always vote to close no matter how often the audit system throws them at me), but why would the system take a question that's actually supposed to be in the queue and use it for auditing? Shouldn't those be exempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a confusing case, however looking at the timeline clears it up. The system created the audit 17 hours ago (at this writing) and it sat in the queue until you happen to get it in review. By that time there were already 3 close votes, hence the confusion.

You're probably thinking it should be removed once the post receives close votes, that thought passed through my mind too, but I suppose the overhead just isn't worth it.

I know situations like this are annoying, but close queue audits are always tricky, it would be quite hard to make it otherwise; especially on a site with such a.. unique closing situation as Ask Ubuntu. As long as you aren't constantly failing audits it isn't a big deal ;)

Comment: The timeline is diamond-mod-only?

Comment: @muru There is a non mod timeline, but I can never remember how to access it. Either way, I don't believe that one would hold the information needed to answer this question. I'll look into it. (to directly answer your question though: yes)

Comment: @muru [Here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/543159/timeline) is the non mod timeline, but as I thought it doesn't contain this information.