# Are you tested with Duplicates in the review queues?

Tags: support, duplicates, review-audits

In the review queues I have never once been tested with a question that has been flagged as duplicate. Does SE not test you on those? And if so, why not? Or have I just not had any?

Comment: They probably aren't tested because they cannot expect you to know of every single duplicate on your site.

Comment: @Seth but you can chose a random duplicate for a question and require the reviewer to reject it?

Comment: @ByteCommander That's not a good judge of reviews. Remember, the people ruining review aren't the ones throwing close votes around (usually). They're the ones calling everything they see "ok" even when it isn't.

Comment: @Seth So the test will detect those who click on OK although it was no duplicate but just a random question (which might occasionally be a true duplicate though...) - I don't understand your last comment therefore.

Comment: @ByteCommander What do you expect them to do if they don't think it should be closed? They click "leave open" or "looks ok", exactly what they would do if they weren't paying attention in the first place.

Comment: @Seth Okay, then SE could add tests with approved duplicates and require the reviewer to confirm them instead of leaving open.

Comment: @ByteCommander Duplicates are a lot more subjective than the other close reasons, and we get enough complaints just about those audits!

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12214/158442?